# using mysql queues to list the number of students

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm learning mySQL and I'm a little confused how I can use mySQL queries to say...list the total number of Employees in a Department.

Emp(eid: integer, ename: string, age: integer, salary: real)
Works(eid: integer, did: integer, pct_time: integer)
Dept(did: integer, budget: real, managerid: integer)

*this is the example my book is working with but I guess I'm just asking can someone help me walk through an example using the sum aggregate function? Or would I be totally off in using this to say...list the total number of employees?

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the table `Dept` with `Works` first using `LEFT JOIN` in order for all records (*all department*) to be shown on the final result, those departments that have no employee will be on the list but with value of `0`.

```
SELECT  a.Did, COUNT(b.DId) TotalEmployee
FROM    Dept a
        LEFT JOIN Works b
            ON a.Did = b.DId
GROUP   BY a.Did
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: I'm not sure using aliases is the best idea here, it may be confusing. Just a thought

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use `SUM`, like you said. So, you would first need to `Join` the tables, and then take a SUM of the employee_id row.

```
Select Emp.eid, SUM(Emp.eid) as employee_sum From, Dept.did
Emp
LEFT JOIN Works On
Emp.eid = Works.eid
INNER JOIN Dept ON
Works.did = Dept.did
Group By Emp.eid, Dept.did
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to simply using joins:

**Select count(E.eid)**

**from Emp E,Works W,Dept D**

**where (E.eid = W.eid AND D.did = W.did**);

**Works** table would be linking the two tables together ie **Emp** and **Dept**.
So this query will return you only the no of Employees in a department.